# Pixelated Screen/Fonts

Tags: 20.04, gnome, graphics, fonts, display-resolution

Ever since I installed Ubuntu on this laptop, fonts seem a bit pixelated. I'm pretty sure this doesn't have anything to do with the screen resolution because when I take a screenshot it still shows up. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

See how the text is pixelated? It's harder to read, as if the font is too small for the screen or something. I tried playing around with the size in GNOME Tweaks but the screen still seems a bit pixelated and a bit blurry.

Is there a font issue, or does this have something to do with graphics or the screen?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Did you try to change the setting at `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/font-rgba-order` with `dconf-editor`? Or, the "Antialiasing" option in **Fonts** tab of `gnome-tweaks`?

Comment: @FedKad there is no such option/setting (whatever it's called) in dconf-editor called "font-rgba-order" in /org/gnome/desktop/interface. Is there something I didn't install?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 21.10. If you specify your own version somebody may help you. Did you look at Antialiasing in `gnome-tweaks` as I pointed in my first comment also? **Scaling Factor** should be set at 1.0.

Comment: @FedKad whoops! Sorry! I edited my question. I am using 20.04. Yes, I looked in GNOME Tweaks and I tried all the antialising settings but it didn't change anything. I also have Scaling Factor at 1.

Comment: Please, also see this web page: http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/subpixel.php It may help you at least in eliminating any subpixel problem with your screen.

Comment: @FedKad I used the image and there is a black line on the left side, which means that my screen is RGB. What should I do? EDIT: I also found an `rgba-order` setting in dconf-editor in /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings. Changing the order didn't seem to help.

Comment: I fail to see the problem in your screenshot. Perhaps it's difficult to discerne because there is no reference for scale. This just looks like font antialiasing to me. Can you post a screenshot of your entire screen and also tell us the screen resolution of your display? We are all assuming that the screen is set to the native resolution.

Comment: @Nmath I thought it showed in screenshots but I'm not sure anymore. I think that it's a resolution problem. I have a "full HD 16:9 display" (which means 1280x1920) which is what the sticker that was initially on the laptop when ordered said.

Comment: OK, if you'd like help with this please make sure that you are being accurate with details especially if we ask for clarification. If you're not sure, look it up or research until you are sure. I've never heard of that resolution being used.  1920x1080 is the most common screen resolution. But again, without seeing an uncropped, uncompressed screenshot of the entire screen, the partial screenshot does not help identify a resolution or antialiasing problem. You need to determine the native resolution and also make sure that's the resolution being used.